# What is this nameless variable? C

Tags: c

Take this code

```
int main() {
     int *p = &(int){2};
}
```

What is this? `&(int){2}` A variable without a name? What's the point of a nameless variable in C? How does the compiler know to keep it on the stack if it's not assigned to a name?

Furthermore, if I declare a nameless value such as

```
int main() {
   (int){3};
}
```

is there a way to get the address of this nameless variable back in a fully portable way? (fully portable as in, it's gonna work on every platform no matter how the stack is arranged)

After years of coding in C I had no idea you could declare nameless variables like that. Is there a reason you would want to use this over regular named variables?

Comment: The expression `(int){2}` is a [*compound literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal). The ampersand `&` is the [*address-of* operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Address_of).

Comment: And the statement `(int){3};` is by itself useless. The result of the expression `(int){3}` is thrown away.

Comment: `malloc(42)` *also* gives you a "nameless variable". But you can still get at it if you have a pointer to it, such as with your first example.

Comment: "How does the compiler know to keep it on the stack if it's not assigned to a name?" Variable names are one of the first things a compiler strips out. The program binary doesn't know or care about the names our meat computers use to talk about memory.

Comment: `(int){3};` is not a declaration, it's an expression. In this context, it's not different from writing `3;` but in other contexts it is different: it is an *lvalue*, so you could take its address with the `&` operator. If you don't do so, there is no portable way to get the address (and indeed, the compiler might well optimise it out of existence).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a **compound literal**.  Its lifetime is the same as a local variable declared in the same scope.

One common use is to assign all values of a struct after it has been initialized:

```
struct s {
  int a;
  float b;
};

struct s s1;
s1 = (struct s){3, 4.0};
```

Or to pass its address to a function that requires a pointer to a valid object, but you don't plan on using that object after the function has returned:

```
int x[5];
memcpy(x, (int[5]){3,4,5,6,7}, sizeof(int[5]));
```

Comment: Just call it a constructor for cheap people.